# Access a Mac with a broken display remotely

Tags: macos, mac

I have this Macbook with a completely broken display. An external display isn't working, probably it needs some setup.
I can see the Mac in the network and I login with admin user. But the problem is that I didn't have ssh or VNC access enabled, so I can't do anything besides looking at the files.
Is there a way to enable ssh/vnc by writing a bash file or something that the computer will execute?

Comment: No, not really. What you need needs to be installed/enabled locally before used remotely.

Comment: Fixing hardware remotely has become a fairly common evergreen request. You need a local person to assist.

Comment: If the Macbook does boot and you can write to the disk, and to the proper directory, you theoretically could add a startup routine that would enable VNC.  How are you looking at the files?  Do you have the drive mounted on a different machine?

Comment: @squillman I see the computer in my network and connect to it. But I can only see the user's files (~/) and not the ones in Machintosh HD. If I could, I think I could be adding the com.apple.RemoteDesktop.plist in Library/Preferences. I was thinking that maybe I could add a bash file to this user that could write the preferences file upon start up???

Comment: How are you connecting to it?  Via shared folders?  If all you can access are user files then you likely won't be able to do what you need to do since the commands to do so require elevated access (sudo).

Comment: You can get to the Mac's files by starting up in [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac) but idk what you'd need to do from there to enable screen sharing.

Comment: Ok, thank you all